# Android Layout skewed for different screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, android-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/layout_blue_border"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
    android:outlineProvider="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/abc_control_inset_material">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Moisture Probe Info"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_button_material"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ActvCal"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/display_tv"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/display_tv"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Serial #:"
                android:id="@+id/Serial"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/serial_val"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Battery:"
                android:id="@+id/Battery"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Battery_val"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:text="0"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Firmware Ver:"
                android:id="@+id/Firmware"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Firmware_val"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date:"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/date_val"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MAC Addr:"
                android:id="@+id/MACaddr"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/mac_val"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Latitude"
                android:id="@+id/Long_text"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Latitude_val"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Longitude"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Longitude_val"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Note"
                android:layout_column="8"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Return2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Return2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:outlineProvider="none" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"

            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:outlineProvider="none" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Return2"
            android:text="Return to Main Menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape_grey"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_caption_material"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"           
/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:layout_weight=".1"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new to Android programming. The layout appears correctly on some devices and is cut off on others. I have added margins like "@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" in the XML for the layout. I expected those to be calculated according to the screen size but that is not the case.  How can I mention margin that is calculated according to the available space?

Comment: If you look at your xml code for the first 2 `LinearLayouts` you are setting in the parent `LinearLayout` a `weightSum="1"`, however in the child `LinearLayout` you have `android:layout_weight="1.5"` .. which is more than 1.  Also when using weighted layouts with `LinearLayout` make sure you have the height (for vertical `LinearLayout`) and width (for horizontal `LinearLayout`) set to `0dp`.  In all your layout needs some cleaning up because the weights don't tally its pushing layouts out of visible view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, it is not good that you have so many wrapped layouts one in another.
And second, is very bad to use weight in these cases as Android need a lot of time to count the value inside the deepest component.

In this way you need better to use **TableLayout** for the same purposes.